# Isomorphism between groups defined by set builder notation

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

How is it possible to show that for a set $G = \{x + y\sqrt{3}| x, y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and a set $H = \{2^i*5^j| i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ that the group $[A, +]$ is isomorphic to $[B, *]$ (let $+$ be standard addition and $*$ be standard multiplication between reals)? In particular I am struggling to find a valid function that holds for the homomorphism property.

Comment: I apologize, yes, I made the correction in my post.

Comment: g is defined to be x + y * sqrt(3) for some integers x and y, or are you prompting a different question?

Comment: g=5, I left my glasses at home.

Comment: Is there a function which maps $x+y\sqrt3$ to $2^x5^y$?

Comment: If we try f(x) = x*sqrt(3) we only transfer the square root to the x term, and if we square the entire term we only get x^2 +3y^2 + 2*sqrt(3)*x*y. The issue I think is getting rid of the square root of 3 because it needs to map to some product of 2 and 5, (thank you for your patience). I had considered trying an integral but I don't see how that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because both groups are isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z, +)$.

This gives an isomorphism $G \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to H$:
$$
x + y\sqrt{3} \mapsto (x, y) \mapsto 2^x 5^y
$$
To see that this is a homomorphism, compute:
$$
(x + y\sqrt{3})+(x' + y'\sqrt{3})
=(x + x') + (y+y')\sqrt{3}
\mapsto 2^{x+x'} 5^{y+y'} = \cdots
$$

Comment: Is it possible to prove the groups are isomorphic without using a direct product? (particularly, is it possible to satisfy the homomorphism property?)

Comment: @hdgdjd, sure, just ignore the middle map.

Comment: Could you clarify how it is possible to go from (x+x′) +(y+y')*sqrt[3] to 2^(x+x')5^(y+y')? It looks impossible to me because of the irrationality of Sqrt[3]

Comment: Is it possible to prove that such a second mapping exists? I have been struggling to find it analytically.

Answer (score 1):

Since by definition any number g in G can be represented by (x,y) such that g=x+y*sqrt(3), all you have to show is that the mapping of elements from G to ZXZ is one-one and from there you can use those guaranteed unique x's and y's to go to 2^x*5^y and the isomorphism will be complete. While it would be interesting to find a way to extract the x and y from just the numerical value of the element in G you're already given their existence so the one-one mapping is all you need.

Comment: I need to prove the isomorphism without using a direct product, showing surjectivity, injectivity, and that the homomorphism property is satisfied. Is there a way to find such a function, or is it possible to prove such a thing is true without using an explicit function?

Answer (score 1):

The homomorphism $\varphi : G \to H$ is simply defined 
$$(\forall x,y \in \Bbb Z): \quad \varphi (x+y\sqrt{3})=2^x 5^y$$
and its inverse is
$$(\forall x,y \in \Bbb Z): \quad \varphi^{-1} (2^x5^y) = x+y\sqrt{3}.$$

Sure, it seems a bit weird to define functions like this, but after looking closely you should realize that these are proper functions, that is, they are mapping every element in their domain and we never have the case that one element is mapped to two or more.

We just need to make sure these are homomorphisms, which if fairly straightforward. We have $\forall x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 \in \mathbb Z:$

$\begin{array}
\ \varphi\bigg((x_1+y_1 \sqrt{3})+(x_2+y_2 \sqrt{3})\bigg) &= \varphi \bigg((x_1+x_2) + (y_1+y_2)\sqrt{3}\bigg) \\
&= 2^{x_1+x_2}5^{y_1+y_2} \\
&=2^{x_1}2^{x_2}5^{y_1}5^{y_2} \\
&=2^{x_1}5^{y_1}\cdot2^{x_2}5^{y_2} \\
&= \varphi(x_1+y_1\sqrt{3})\varphi(x_2+y_2\sqrt{3})
\end{array}$

thus $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, could you should that $\varphi^{-1}$ is a homomorphism then, completing the proof?

**Note:** Also, it should be clear that these are both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ bijective. But as others have stated, you can use the argument that $G\cong \Bbb Z^2$ and $H \cong \Bbb Z^2$ and that isomorphisms are equivalence relations providing:
$$G \cong \Bbb Z^2 \text{ and } H \cong \Bbb Z^2 \implies G \cong \Bbb Z^2 \text{ and } \Bbb Z^2 \cong H \implies G \cong \Bbb Z^2 \cong H \implies G \cong H.$$